# UNIX script to send an alert mail if file size of a flat file is zero or otherwise

Tags: shell, unix, alert

I'm looking for ways to have an automated process that checks the size of a flat file in a particular location if it is zero or otherwise. Currently, I am doing it manually by going to the location and to check it. This is tedious work since I'm doing this from time to time. Could someone guide me from here? It could be a shell script in a server that when I run, it will send an email to myself and others.

Hoping for your kind response. All I see here are batch files which is not applicable to me.

sample:

location

server_name/folder1/folder2/folder3

file: test_file.dat 0 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Test file with full path
if [ ! -s /tmp/test.dat ]; then
    mail 'alert@example.com' -s 'test.dat is empty' < /dev/null
fi;
```

Create a cron job using **crontab -e** that will check every five minutes

```
*/5 * * * * /home/user/check.sh
```

Be sure to set the execute bit on /home/user/check.sh with

```
chmod +x /home/user/check.sh
```

Notes:

- The email content is the subject, there is no other text in the message because there is enough space to communicate the information on the subject line
- You may need to use a program other than **mail**, depending on your OS, and you might have to update the command line parameters as well

Comment: Hi, with regards to the script, can you let me know where is the conditional statement? Seems like the script didn't return any subject nor email content. thanks for your help by the way

Comment: I used your example by removing the ! because I wanted to send the file via email if it was Not Empty. Also of course replace /dev/null with the actual file name so the body of the email is now the file contents. Note that without a body it will toss an error, and (oddly enough) my mail client refused to download it (it was on the server, so it worked perfectly, but my mail client didn't like it). Since I wanted the content anyway, I didn't care.